# Wrapping an html String with JQuery

Tags: jquery

So I have made the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3dTK/3/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = '<div><div class="c">1</div><div class="c">2</div></div>';
    //approach 1
    var $html = $(html);
    var $elts = (".c", $html);
    console.log($elts.length);
    //approach 2
    $elts = $(".c", $(html));
    console.log($elts.length);  
});
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Why do these two approaches differ?

EDIT:

This is JQuery 1.10.1 by the way.

Comment: What do you expect from `(".c", $html);`?

Comment: @j08691 I am expecting a jquery object containing the elements with class c, so in this case the two inner div elements.

Comment: But without the `$` in front of the parenthesis, it's not a jQuery object. Only the `$html` inside is a jQuery object, the rest is ignored. You could have `("foo", $html);` and still get a result of 1.

Comment: `("comma operator claims another victim", $html)`

Comment: @j08691 You are totally right, its just a missing $. waaaah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the first one is not a jquery object :

```
var $elts = (".c", $html);
```

Doing `(".c", $html)` will only mean the var will equal the last value inside the bracket wich is the jQuery $html object.

Test it, try this

```
var $elts = ('anything', 4);
console.log($elts) // = 4;
```

if you do `var $elts = $('.c', $html)`, both log will be the same :

http://jsfiddle.net/L3dTK/5/

Comment: That comment mixed with your name made me smile :)

Answer (score 4):

`var $elts = (".c", $html);` considers element (outer) `div`

while

`$elts = $(".c", $(html));` considers divs having `.c`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not understanding your explanation, could you elaborate a little bit.

Comment: first statements considers outer (parent div only) because you have not used `$`. whereas second statement considers number of elements having class `c`.  you got it?